# Is there simple way of changing timezone between dto and entities at database?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I write application on Spring Boot with Spring Data(postgresql).

I have the following case. I want to store in database time at UTC timezone, and parse it to/from "America/San-Paulo" timezone in dto.

For example: in controller I get dto with LocalDateTime in America/San-Paulo timezone. And I want to save it in database in UTC timezone.

I can do in when mapping from dto to entity. But maybe there is another simple way like setting some properties of hibernate/spring?

Comment: Don’t use `LocalDateTime` neither for a UTC time nor for a time in America/Sao_Paulo time zone. For the former prefer `OffsetDateTIme` and store as `timestamp with time zone` in PostgreSQL. For the latter use `ZonedDateTime`. Not that it saves you the conversion.

Comment: By *parse* do you mean convert a `String` to `LocalDateTime` object or other date-time object? It’s what the word would mean in your context. Why would you want to do that? It’s better avoided. Don’t handle date and time as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java 8, we have the Date/Time API under `java.time`!

(1) Convert the timezone in annotated `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate`, and `@PostLoad` methods.

For example, in annotated `@PostLoad`, convert from UTC to America/San-Paulo.

```java
private static ZoneId UTC_ZONE = ZoneId.of("UTC");
private static ZoneId LOCAL_ZONE = ZoneId.of("America/San_Paulo");

private LocalDateTime dateTime;

@PostLoad
public void toLocal() {
  dateTime = dateTime.atZone(UTC_ZONE).withZoneSameInstant(LOCAL_ZONE).toLocalDateTime();
}
```

(2) Assuming you are using Jackson, you can write a custom serializer/deserializer.

**UPDATE:**

With PostgreSQL, you can use the type `timestamp with time zone`. By default, if you insert/update the column, it will convert the value to UTC.

In JPA:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone")
```

**UPDATE (22-07-01):**

You could also use an `AttributeConverter`.

Comment: Note: It's probably better to use `ZonedDateTime` because it stores the timezone.